# Do we have to consider the order in which these three bags are chosen?

Tags: probability

> If one ball is drawn from bags A, B, and C, then find the probability that each ball is a red ball.

[image]

Do we have to consider the order in which these three bags are chosen?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m62st.png)

Comment: If you consider the order and you get your calculations correctly, you will get the same result as if you did not consider the order. Or, rather, the probability is the same no matter what the order is. What is more disconcerting is: from the picture it is not even clear whether we know how many red balls are in the bag $B$.

Comment: I have edited the image, red balls in B are 40. And is 55/2088 the correct answer?

Comment: Why are all but one  row totals different from  $\Sigma$ row entries ?

Comment: @trueblueanil different bags have different number of balls and some values are missing

Comment: $55/2088$ ... looks right to me. It is the same as $\frac{33}{108}\times\frac{40}{112}\times\frac{21}{87}$.